# Ruby on Rails project, running into a syntax error don't see what I'm missing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is the error:
_post.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' ensure ^~~~~~

Problem is there is no line17.  The partial this error is produce on looks as follows:

```
<div class='col-sm-3 single-post-card' id=<%= post_path(post.id %> >
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-block'>
      <h4 class='post-text'>
        <%= truncate(post.title, :length => 60 %>
      </h4>
      <div class='post-content'>
        <div class='posted-by'>Posted by <%= post.user.name %></div>
        <h3><%= post.title %> </h3>
        <p><%= post.content %></p>
        <%= link_to  "I'm interested", post_path(post.id), class: 'interested' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only 15 lines of code.  it is rendered here:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="side-menu" class="col-sm-3">
    </div>

    <div id="main-content" class='col-sm-9'>
      <%= render @posts %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm sure it's something small I'm missing but I can't seem to figure it out, a second pair of eyes would be helpful.

Comment: Post stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a closing parenthesis on the very first line

```
id=<%= post_path(post.id %>
```

Comment: And on at least one other line

Comment: There is one on that line, I have 2 >, I seperated it with a space

Comment: @Sohel not talking about `>`